# Create a OneToMany mapping of an interface

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql

I've been going around this for a couple of days without actually achieving much.  I would like to create a OneToMany relationship between an object and some interfaces.  This is the basic example

```
public class Contact {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "contact")
  private List<ContactFacade> facades;
}

public interface ContactFacade {
  public Contact getContact() { }
}

public class ContactFacebook implements ContactFacade {
  @ManyToOne
  private Contact contact;
  public Contact getContact() { }
}

public class ContactTwitter implements ContactFacade {
  @ManyToOne
  private Contact contact;
  public Contact getContact() { }
}
```

I can certainly do a query like this to get all `ContactFacade` for a given contact:

```
SELECT package.name.ContactFacade WHERE contact.id = :theid
```

But i haven't been able to really map it as an attribute to another class.  Is at all possible to do this?  Is there another way?  I would really to hate to keep an entity inside the `Contact` just to the query.

Answer (score 1):

Associate the `ContactFacade` with an abstract Contact class, let each facade which extends to it implement getContact(..).

```
public interface ContactFacade {
  public Contact getContact() { }
}

@Entity
@Inheritance
public abstract class Contact implements ContactFacade {
private Set<Contact > contacts;

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "contact")
   public Set<Contact> getContacts() {
       return notes;
   }
}

@Entity
public class ContactFacebook extends Contact {
  @ManyToOne
  private Contact contact;
  public Contact getContact() { }
}
...
```